# Facebook Invite Friends API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to invite people to my website from facebook. I found a code and it's work with a few issue. the code show me all my friends when I click invite button first time but popup show me only six people when I close popup and second time reclick invite button. Sorry for bad English.

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>My Great Canvas app</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
   </script>
   <script>
     FB.init({ 
       appId:'APP_ID',
       cookie:true, 
       status:true,
       xfbml:true 
     });
function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
   message: 'My diaolog...'});
}
   </script>
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> Facebook Invite Friends</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm waiting for help